# Launch/Refresh a specific route takes too long to load angular universal

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have a angular universal app hosted in firebase . I am facing a wierd issue. when i am launching the application without any route (https://example.com). it is loading perfectly fine . but when I am trying to launch/refresh a specific url (https://example.com/route1) from browser, it is taking more than 8 sec to load. when I am navigating to that url through the homepage , it is loading within a sec . but when i am trying to navigate directly to that url from browser , it is taking time.

All my routes are lazy loaded but no luck . I am not sure why it is taking time

Answer (score 0):

How is your server configured for subroutes ?

Usually in Angular, a best practice is to use hash routing

```js
routerModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
```

This will render your URLs as such

```markdown
https://example.com/#/route1
```

Forcing Angular to manage the sub-routes of its own application, rather than the server having to handle it.

Try this, see if it resolves your issue ?

Comment: hi @MGX. Thanks for the quick response. but Hash routing does not work with angular universal. When I am trying to use that  then SSR is not working (can not see the title and meta tags of individual pages).